# Bitbucket send Slack notifications on deployment started

Tags: slack, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I'd like to send Slack notifications to a channel when a deployment starts. The current available notifications are for deployment success, failure or stopped but nothing for the start of a deployment.

Is there a workaround to get the notification when the deployment begins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Atlassian's Slack notification pipe https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/slack-notify

```yaml
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:

    - &slack-notify-variables
        WEBHOOK_URL: $SLACK_WEBHOOK
        # ...

    - &deploy-step
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/slack-notify:2.0.0
            variables:
              <<: *slack-notify-variables
              MESSAGE: "Deployment to $BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT started"
          - bash deploy.sh $BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          deployment: my-staging-environment

      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          deployment: my-production-environment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use git tags (or are willing to move to using tags), e.g. `1.2.3` you can be notified that a tag is pushed and ensure your trigger is initiated by those tags. Then, you can receive a notification once the deployment has completed as well, for a total of 2 separate notifications. This won't work for every situation but it can at least notify you of a production level deployment that is about to be initiated (which is how I use it).

To do this:

1. Go into your "Repository Settings"
2. Select "Settings" under Slack
3. Under `Repository-wide` (or a branch, if you prefer) select `tag created`
4. Also ensure the other `deployment succeeded` and `deployment failed` notifications are still selected.

Then, in your pipelines update it to this:

```yaml
pipelines:
  tags:
    # Matches tags like '1.2.3'
    '*.*.*':
      # ... your tag-specific pipeline steps and etc...
```